# question on autocompletetextview in android

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have written a logic where by default if anyone wants to clear the conents of autocompletetextview(AV) then it will become one. But I want when I bring focus inside AV then it should be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`onFocusChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnFocusChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener%29) to detect a change in the focus, and if it just lost focus, check the content. otherwise clear the data.